# Work with a columnar Pandas dataframe data format to generate a hierarchical tree structure

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, data-structures

I'm trying to figure out a good way to create an abstraction of the following dataframe in Pandas obtained from an excel file:

```
Date | ID   | Company  | ProjectID | ProjectName     | ProcessLevel1 | Process1Name     | ProcessLevel2 | Process2Name    | ProcessLevel3 | Process3Name | ProcessLevel4 | Process4Name | ...
2020 | 1234 | ABCCorp. | XYZ123    | SomeProjectName |       P1      | Data Preparation |               |                 |               |              |               |              | ...
2020 | 1234 | ABCCorp. | XYZ123    | SomeProjectName |       P1      | Data Preparation |       P2      | Data Extraction |               |              |               |              | ...
2020 | 1234 | ABCCorp. | XYZ123    | SomeProjectName |       P1      | Data Preparation |       P2      | Data Cleansing  |               |              |               |              | ...
```

The levels are hierarchical, and I want to create a link of the flow of the projects with different levels showing its previous level as well that comes before it. As shown above, there are multiple levels of the processes as names and levels, with L1 being the highest level (first step). Some steps are done concurrently, and have processes the follow it and branch off into multiple parallel processes with potential subprocesses. Essentially, this is a tree-like hierarchy with `P1` level, `P2` level, `P3` level, etc. for around 30 levels.

Essentially, it can look something like

```
P1                          Data Preparation
                           /                 \
P2                  Data Extraction        Data Cleansing
                   /         |            /     |   \     \
P3            Categorical Numerical     Strip Split Null  Remove
```

I am trying to create a data abstraction to plot this, do various calculations (i.e., how many subprocesses are spawned from a particular process node, how many processes are in the P3 level, what is the process hierarchy given a certain node in this process tree, etc.). I don't think doing Pandas operations are useful here, and I am trying to make the pre-processing of this data highly efficient in order to do group-by operations based on `Company` or `ProjectID`, in order to show the hierarchies and highlight different aspects. In addition, if using a tree, it won't necessarily be balanced since some hierarchies may go deep into one leaf node, while others have a larger number of children but stop short in the hierarchy levels.

I have tried the `pd.melt()` operation in order to melt these together, but this isn't exactly the best way to approach it, since two columns for each process level (namely, `ProcessLevelXX` and `ProcessXXName`) are in separate columns, which I want to keep together for hierarchy purposes. Is there either a) an efficient algorithm in Pandas for working with these types of hierarchical data spread out in multiple columns and with smart Pandas operations I can map these relations, or b) a data structure or algorithm I can use to efficiently compute and perform `groupby`'s? This is one area of concern, since with a data abstraction, efficient re-arranging of the tree data structure (which is what I am thinking of since the data is hierarchical in nature) would be very inefficient. However, I don't know how to construct an efficient, elegant paradigm to do so. If this data was available in a database, that would be ideal, but this is not the case here (just given in this format in Excel).

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical indexing in Pandas uses what they call a MultiIndex.

The idea is that instead of your index being a single series, your index is like its own DataFrame with multiple series.  For your example data, the first level of the MultiIndex would be named P1 and its value would be "Data Preparation" for all rows.  The second level would be P2 and would have two values, "Data Extraction" and "Data Cleansing".  And so on.

Any individual row will have a value for every level of the MultiIndex, so for example you might have a row whose index value is ["Data Preparation", "Data Cleansing", "Split"].

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm just trying to think if this hierarchical data would slow down any type of re-arranging or filtering (for example, `groupby`) by companyName, projectName, and a few different types of groupby operations. Would it be better to just "abstract away" and create other efficient tree highlighting methods for groupby operations?

Comment: @qxzsilver: I don't think it will be slow.  Whether some other abstraction is better or worse for your use case is not something I can answer.